# Uncaught TypeError: changeTodoText.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript

trying to fires an event but the console tell me that is not a function

```
var changeTodoText = document.getElementsByClassName("listeItemTodo");
    changeTodoText.addEventListener("click", function () {
                alert("go");
            }, false);
```

/*          Note that i'm using the strict mode    */

Comment: try changing   var changeTodoText to   function changeTodoText() and return the array

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an *array* of elements with the class name. If you're trying to find one particular element, use an `id` instead, like this:

```
<div id="listeItemTodo"></div>
```

You can then get the element with this:

```
var changeTodoText = document.getElementById("listeItemTodo");
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/fm9vzny3/) is a JSFiddle to show how my solution works.

Comment: We don't need Yet Another Answer to this question.

Comment: My solution is different to the other one, so it's not "yet another answer". Only trying to help here - you're welcome to suggest improvements to my answer if it's not good enough for you.

Comment: I'm not talking about the other answer *here* (as is perfectly clear from my identical comment on that answer). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method

Comment: thnX man but i have a lot of the same tag and i want to get them by class name if he return an array i should loop to get them all thnx i will try